# Tkinter button freezing

Tags: python, tkinter

Say you have this program:

```
import os
from tkinter import *
from time import sleep

def wait():
    print('waiting 5 seconds...')
    sleep(5)

def close():
    root.destroy()


root = Tk()
b = Button(text='click', command=wait)
close = Button(text='close', command=close)
b.pack()
close.pack()
mainloop()
```

After I click the button "click", the button freezes for 5 seconds, then goes back to normal. How do I make it so that I doesn't freeze? (I don't want to remove the button animation, I just want it so it does the button animation, then waits 5 seconds) Also, when I click "click", I can't click "close". How do I fix this?

Comment: `sleep` does exaclty what it advertises - it puts the whole app to sleep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

time.sleep() pauses the whole application (including your tkinter window), meaning it'll freeze. You can, however, use the `root.after()` function. A working example:

```
import tkinter

class MyApp:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.root = parent
        self.root.geometry("400x400")
        self.frame = tkinter.Frame(parent)
        self.frame.pack()
        self.root.after(3000, self.delayed)

    def delayed(self):
        print('I was delayed')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    app = MyApp(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Using `root.after` won't freeze your application during the wait time.
Note: You have to specify the wait time in milliseconds (1 second = 1000 milliseconds)

I hope I could help you!

Answer (score 1):

Since `time.sleep()` is a blocking function, no code will be run until the function call is complete. To avoid this happening, you can use `threading` to create a thread that waits the five seconds, but allows other code to run. This is called multiprocessing, which you can read more about multiprocessing [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html).

```py
import threading
import time
import tkinter
import os

def wait():
    print('waiting 5 seconds...')
    threading.Thread(target=time.sleep, args=(5,)).start()

def close():
    root.destroy()


root = tkinter.Tk()
b = tkinter.Button(text='click', command=wait)
close = tkinter.Button(text='close', command=close)
b.pack()
close.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Technically this example is correct but with that Threading target, it would immediately jump to the next line and not wait.  You would need it to jump to another function that has the time.sleep and have the rest of the function be migrated to the Threading target.

Comment: @tayler6000 Then I think I misunderstood the question. I interpreted as disabling the button for 5 seconds, but I guess I was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Tkinter can be a little confusing at first.  Most people think Tkinter is running on a separate thread from their code but in reality, it's not.  Which means when you use time.sleep, your program freezes for that amount of time, which includes Tkinter.  If the goal you're trying to go for is Wait5Seconds(); DoSomething(); I would recommend doing the following:

```
import time

def wait():
    print('waiting 5 seconds...')
    stop = time.time() + 5
    while time.time() <= stop:
      time.sleep(.001)
    DoSomething()
```

This isn't the perfect solution either as it still involves that sleep but it's better.  You can replace that with `pass` but the reason I tend to put a time.sleep in a while loop specifically designed for waiting is that if you just have a `while x: pass` it will ramp up your CPU Core which can cause significant lag in a low core count computer.  The idea here is just to put something there that takes up some time so your CPU doesn't go crazy.  A possible alternative that I haven't tested myself but could work and would cause no Tkinter delay is `print('\r')` Which just sets the cursor back to the beginning of the line.  Which will overwrite what's there if you didn't go to a new line yet, so be mindful.  But that could work better as outputting to the screen actually takes up a decent amount of time in terms of processing power, but won't block Tkinter.  To test this (assuming you're on Windows) you can press LCtrl+LShift+Esc to open Task Manager, press more details (if necessary) then go to the Performance tab.  Make sure CPU is selected then right-click on the graph and select Change Graph To > Logical Processors, this will show you the utilization of each core individually.  By default, python will only run in one core, though it can switch what core it's using at random.